# Scraping data and putting it in different columns using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have written a script to scrape data from a website. It has 2 columns. But I want to add another column to it (abstract column). How can I do this inside the same loop? I need to get the 'abstract' data in the third column. Image attached below.

[image]

The code is below:

```
    import requests 
    import csv      
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    

    file = "Details181.csv"    
    Headers = ["Category", "Vulnerabilities", "Abstract"]   
    url = "https:/en/weakness?po={}"    

    with open(file, 'w', newline='') as f:  

       csvriter = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')     

       csvriter.writerow(Headers)     

       for page in range(1, 131):     

          r = requests.get(url.format(page))     

          soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')   

          for title in soup.select('div.title > h1'):   

              csvriter.writerow([title.strip() for title in                
                  title.text.split(':')]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I guess `abstract` and `category, vulnerability` maybe have the common father div element.

Then I try to find the common div and extract data in every loop, finally, I verified my guess, I also add default value for `vulnerability` when `title` has no `vulnerability content`

The following code run successfully

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

file = "Details181.csv"
Headers = ["Category", "Vulnerabilities", "Abstract"]
url = "https://vulncat.fortify.com/en/weakness?po={}"

with open(file, 'w', newline='') as f:
    csvriter = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    csvriter.writerow(Headers)

    for page in range(1, 131):
        r = requests.get(url.format(page))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

        # find the common father div info
        all_father_info = soup.find_all("div", class_="detailcell weaknessCell panel")
        for father in all_father_info:

            # find the son div info, then extract data
            son_info_12 = father.find('h1').text.split(":")
            if len(son_info_12) == 2:
                category, vulnerability = son_info_12[0].strip(), son_info_12[1].strip()
            elif len(son_info_12) == 1:
                category = son_info_12[0].strip()
                vulnerability = ""
            else:
                category, vulnerability = "", ""

            # find the son div info, then extract abstract
            abstract = father.find("div", class_="t").text.strip()

            # write data into csv file
            csvriter.writerow([category, vulnerability, abstract])
```

Comment: Tried this with the abstract_data, but it isn't going anywhere : abstract_data = soup.findall("div",{"class":"t"}).get_text()

Comment: Does the job. You're awesome.